# Troubleshooting C# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My program asks a user to enter *Height*, *Weight*.
Calculated BMI gets printed.

My problem is the output. It is constantly Zero.

height:`180`

weight:`65`

Expected output: `20.1`

Calculation logic is:

```
BMI = weight / height^2 (squared)
```

Where is my error?

My code below:

```
//declare variables
        int weight;
        int height;
        double BMI;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your weight:");
        weight = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//Get weight from keyboard

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your height:");
        height = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//get height from keyboard

        BMI = Math.Sqrt(height);//Square the height
        
        BMI = weight / height;//SET BMI TO WEIGHT DIVIDED BY HEIGHT SQUARED

        //if the BMI is less than 25
        if (BMI < 25)     {
            Console.WriteLine("BMI =" + BMI + " Congratulations! your BMI is perfect!.");     }

        else if (BMI > 30)     {
            Console.WriteLine("BMI =" + BMI + " Be careful! risks could lead to obesity.");     }

        else     {
            Console.WriteLine("BMI =" + BMI + " Please consider seeing a doctor, as you are of high risk of obesity.");     }
```

output I get is:

> 0

Comment: Math.sqrt returns the Square Root, not the Square. Either go old school `h*h` or `Math.Pow(h, 2)`.

Comment: Hello, can you accept my answer, please and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[`Math.Sqrt(Double) Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sqrt?view=net-5.0) is used to get the square root of a specified number.

To do exponentiation, we can use [`Math.Pow(Double, Double) Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=net-5.0).

Just call it like:

```
BMI = weight / (Math.Pow(height, 2));
```

> BMI = Math.Sqrt(height);//Square the hieght

Besides, if you want to get the square of height, you need to define a new variable to store it.

```
int squarevalue = Math.Pow(height, 2)
```

Rather than saving it to variable `BMI`.

Answer (score 0):

**I** - Declare and Initialize variables like so:

```
        //declare variables
        int weight = 0;
        int height = 0;
        double BMI = 0;
        Boolean conversion;
```

**II** - Use TryParse to accept user input:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your height:");
            conversion = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out height);

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your weight:");
            conversion = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out weight);
```

**III** - Use try catch clause for ***DivideByZeroException*** as follows:

```
        try
        {
            BMI = Math.Round((weight / Math.Pow(height, 2))*10000,1);
        }   catch(DivideByZeroException myException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Divided by Zero", myException.Message);
        }
```

**IV** - You have an error in your logic.
Here is my fix:

```
BMI = Math.Round((weight / Math.Pow(height, 2))*10000,1);
```